How to retrieve all users assigned to a project in YouTrack using the YouTrack API?
I need to retrieve the list of all users assigned to a given project using the YouTrack API. Does anyone know what the correct api endpoint is to retrieve this info?
I've tried looking into project teams? But I couldn't get that to work.

If you want to retrieve assignees from all the existing issues in a project, then you can follow these steps and then filter out assignees from the returned JSON.
If you just want to get a list of potential assignees, you can just retrieve the assignee field values from the project settings as described here. Instead of posting data at the last step, you should use GET.
